# Conda libraries not loading in PyCharm

Tags: python, anaconda, pycharm

So, i can't seem to have PyCharm work correctly with Conda.

I installed Anaconda following step by step the procedure on their site (download bash script, execute it). It is installed in ~/anaconda3, as default. I then installed PyCharm Community edition using snap.

I then launched PyCharm, and created a Conda environment in it. The problem is, i can't load any library in PyCharm. I'm getting : "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'".
Having had this problem before on other systems, I made sure that I'm using conda and not another python interpreter. I even tried to run the python from the environment in a terminal, and pandas load without an error there.

I included a screenshot to try and show every test I made.

EDIT : As Dan mentioned, I was running the wrong python in my example. Running the python from my environment indeed does yield the same error as running through PyCharm. Although, the problem is now that I don't know why I have this message, since 'conda install pandas' tells me that the package is already installed.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, seems like i messed up the screenshot upload. Here is a link : https://ibb.co/RcpSBhZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is that panda might be installed in another python interpreter than the one in your project. In your screenshot, you seem to have `cd`'ed to the virtual environment of anaconda. However, you ran python like so:

```
$ python
```

instead of like so:

```
$ ./python
```

If you try it again with the latter, you'll see importing panda will not work.

---

This is a security feature in Linux, running scripts outside of `$PATH` needs to be a valid path, not just the file name. So you don't run malicious scripts by mistake.

For example, let's say you downloaded and extracted a directory from the internet. You want to list the files in it, and you do the following

```
$ cd directory-name
$ ls
```

If that directory had an executable called `ls` in it that does some really malicious things, you would accidentally run that scripts without realizing until it's too late.

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I made that mistake. So indeed, when i use the right python bin, i get the same mistake in shell that i get in PyCharm, which is expected.
Problem is : it does seem like pandas is also installed on conda. When i run conda install pandas, i get a "# All requested packages already installed." message.

Comment: I don't have experience with conda, but my guess would be that the wrong interpreter is being loaded in the conda environment. So when running `conda install pandas` it's attempting to install it in the wrong environment. You can verify that by running `which python` or `type python`, and both will tell you which environment is being used for conda.

Comment: So this did the trick. Turns out, by default, when you select a conda environment in PyCharm, it does select the default conda path to installation, BUT it didn't work to select the python bin. So my guess is it defaulted to using another version of python on my system (default one installed in ubuntu I would think). So it was easily solved by giving PyCharm the path to the right python bin (the one in anaconda folder). Thanks a lot.